# Wordpress list users who has their birthday today

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, user-profile

There are more than 800 user profiles in my system and there is an extra field in the user profiles to enter their birthday. (Created with ACF) 
I need to display the names of the users who have their birthday today.

I tried the following query several times but I was unable to match the date with todays date because of the year.

```
<?php
$today = date("M d y");
$blogusers = get_users(array(
    'role'      => 'subscriber',
    'meta_key'  => 'date_of_birth',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
));

foreach($blogusers as $user){
$name = $user->first_name;
$date = $user->date_of_birth;
$date = new DateTime($date);

?>

    <div class="person">
        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right"><?php echo $date->format('M d y'); ?></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$today = date("M d");
$blogusers = get_users(array(
    'role'      => 'subscriber',
    'meta_key'  => 'date_of_birth',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
));

foreach($blogusers as $user){
$name = $user->first_name;
$date = $user->date_of_birth;
$date = date("M d",strtotime($date));
if($today == $date){
?>

    <div class="person">
        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right"><?php echo $date; ?></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


<?php 
    }
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hemu999. This works. I did some minor editing in the code and updated to correct few syntax errors.